# Binded image not appearing in design time

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2017

Having a sample image I'm using in my WPF control for testing purposes.

The image path is `<project_dir>/Assets/Samples/dog.jpg`

When I enter the image path in the source attribute, it works without any problems (either in design and run time):

`<Image Source="/Assets/Samples/dog.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill" />`

However, when I move the image path into my ViewModel, it works only in run time for some reason.

```
public string Image { get; set; }

public MyControlViewModel() {
     Image = "/Assets/Samples/dog.jpg";
}
```

`<Image Source="{Binding Image}" Stretch="UniformToFill" />`

---

I did change the image build action to `Resource`, without any results.

Also tried using the resource URI path (`pack://application:,,,/Assets/Samples/dog.jpg`) - without any results as well.

---

- Is this expected behaviour?
- Why does this happends and how can I get it working in design time as well?

Comment: I have already tried using resource pack URI. Results were the same as with the path in my question, thats why I thought it doesn't matter. I have put it back and still nothing shows up in the design time. DataContext is fine as I am binding few other things in that control and Image is the only issue.

Comment: Sorry, I was reading too fast and confusing run time and design time. Most of the time the question is: why does my image appear in design time, but not in run time.

Answer (score 0):

During design time, do you have your ViewModel (explicitly) bound to the View's DataContext?

- If yes, then Designer should show it. In case if it isn't, rebuild your whole project/ solution.
- If not, then chance is that it won't show up during design time, because the DataContext is unknown. One of the solutions is binding it just for the design sake:

For ex:

```
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"  
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyApp.ViewModels"    
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type vm:MyControlViewModel},IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
```